# Sorting values of heatmap

Tags: python, plot, heatmap

I wrote the code as follows to plot the heatmap and it works fine, but I would like to sort the values horizontally. it didn't take into account my code for sorting, do you have any idea?

```
def plot_cross_tabulation(dataframe, column1, column2, selected_value1, selected_value2):

    dataframe["YEAR_x"] = pd.to_numeric(dataframe["YEAR_x"], errors="coerce")
    sns.set(style="whitegrid")
    if selected_value1 < 0:
        filtered_df1 = dataframe[dataframe["YEAR_x"] == selected_value1]
    else:
        filtered_df1 = dataframe[dataframe["YEAR_x"] == abs(selected_value1)]
    if selected_value2 < 0:
        filtered_df2 = dataframe[dataframe["YEAR_x"] == selected_value2]
    else:
        filtered_df2 = dataframe[dataframe["YEAR_x"] == abs(selected_value2)]
        
        
    filtered_df = pd.concat([filtered_df1, filtered_df2])
    cross_tab = pd.crosstab(filtered_df[column1], filtered_df[column2])
    
    if filtered_df.empty:
        print("No data found for the specified values.")
        return
    cross_tab_sorted = cross_tab.reindex(cross_tab.mean().sort_values().index, axis=0)
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 4))
    sns.heatmap(
        cross_tab,
        annot=True,
        fmt="g",
        cmap="BuPu",
        cbar=False,
        ax=ax,
        annot_kws={"size": 8},
    )
    ax.set_xlabel(f"{column2} at visit {selected_value2}", fontsize=7)
    ax.set_ylabel(f"{column1} at visit {selected_value1}", fontsize=7)
    ax.set_title(
        f"Cross-tabulation of {column1} at visit {selected_value1} and {column2} at visit{selected_value2}",
        fontsize=7,
    )
    ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, fontsize=7)
    ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticklabels(), fontsize=7)
    
    plt.show()
    st.pyplot(fig)
    return fig
```